# Can I make MATLAB ignore a section of code when auto-indenting?

Tags: matlab, editor, auto-indent

I love MATLAB "smart indenting". Ctrl-A, Ctrl-I is hardwired with me. However, in my some-3000-lines script, I have *one* section of about 100 lines of code which I would like not to be touched by MATLAB.

(Why, you ask? That's why:

```
x = ...
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa ...
    - ...
        ( ...
                bbbbbbbbbbbbbb ...
            + ...
                cccccccccccccccccccccc ...
        );
```

That's my way of encoding that this is a difference of two things, one of which is `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`, the other being a set of parentheses, ... etc etc.

So, how can I teach MATLAB to not re-indent this part?

Comment: Crazy people, crazy needs. Give some time to the editor and mathworks, it will further do more smart indentation and probably provide its users to train/teach its editor in say Matlab2042b .

Comment: How about prepending a `%` to each of those lines? Without it they would give an error anyway

Comment: @P0W: MATLAB supports all kinds of in-source commands such as `%#ok<NASGU>`, so it is not completely unthinkable that this even exists already.

Comment: @LuisMendo: I *do* want to run these lines, that's valid code (OK, I forgot the `...` in my example, I will add those).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `%{` and  `%}` for comment block:

```
a = 3;
b = 5;
%{
some other code to be ignored
%}
```

and if you want to toggle this ON, all you need is one more `%` in the right place:

```
a = 3;
b = 5;
%%{
some other code to be ignored
%}
```

Comment: So I just add `%%{` and `%}`, and remove one `%` before cleaning the code? That's smart. And it works, too!

Comment: I will, if this remains the best answer. Any solution that does not involve me finding that location, removing a byte, indenting, finding that location again and re-adding that byte would be even more appreciated ;)